# Where does the period go?

Tags: punctuation, periods, quotation-marks

Which of these is correct?

> Our company has a philosophy that "People Matter".
>
> Our company has a philosophy that "People Matter."

Does the period go inside the quotes here or outside?

Comment: Those aren't quotes, they're speech marks. Personally I'd ditch either and the that and say _Our company has a philosophy: People Matter._

Answer (score 3):

In British English, the period goes outside. In American English, the period goes inside.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [pretty good guide](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/quotation_%28speech%29_marks_punctuation_in_or_out.htm) about the conventions for including punctuation within quotes. Wikipedia has a section on it [in the manual of style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aManual_of_Style#Punctuation_inside_or_outside). In summary though, in American English punctuation tends to go on the *inside*; elsewhere it tends to go on the *outside*, unless the punctuation is firmly part of the quoted text.

As I understand it, the US convention of putting commas and stops *inside* the quotes can be traced back to typesetting problems with movable type. The tiny little stop and comma pieces (or "sorts") could easily fall off the page ("forme") unless there was a larger sort beside them to keep them in place. This convention was observed not just in the US, but elsewhere too. As moveable type started to fall out of fashion in favour of hot metal typesetting, the convention was retained in the US, but abandoned elsewhere in favour of a more logical policy (where the punctuation is only inside the quote marks if it is part of the quote).

Comment: Putting the punctuation inside the quotes makes no sense. How do you distinguish between  "When Shakespeare wrote "To be, or not to be, that is the question,", his use of punctuation was [...]" and "When Shakespeare wrote "To be, or not to be, that is the question", his use of punctuation was [...]" ?

Comment: Well, you certainly wouldn't put the punctuation both *inside **and** outside* the quote as in your example. For illustrating punctuation styles, neither convention is especially useful - better to just indented block quotes, with no quote marks at all.

Comment: Are you sure you don't, at least in British English, simply quote whatever punctuation there was in the original and then punctuate the sentence that contains the quotation in the normal way?